# Correct values of data-frame rows based on reference row

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a large data frame with `K` columns, where in unknown column indices I have the character "X" in it. I wish to replace be some value based on the reference row with `K` columns as well.

I can do it using `for` loop easily:

```
ref_r = mu_df[1, ]
for (n in row.names(mu_df)) {
    idx = which(mu_df[n, ] == "X")
    mu_df[n, idx] = ref_r[idx]
}
```

The above code finds the indices where "X" appears and replaces them in the values in the same position from the `ref_row`.

I wish to optimize it, I was thinking of using 1 of the `apply` family but I couldn't improve by anything.

An example is:

```
mu_df = data.frame(c1=c("A", "-", "X", "-", "B"), c2=c("I", "G", "R", "X", "S"), c3=c("-", "K", "-", "-", "B"), c4=c("Q", "-", "L", "-", "X"), row.names = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"))
```

And the expected output is:

```
   c1 c2 c3 c4
t1  A  I  -  Q
t2  -  G  K  -
t3  A  R  -  L
t4  -  I  -  -
t5  B  S  B  Q
```

How can I optimize it, as I have to process thousands of such data-frames in that manner?

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row/column index of each value of `'X'`.

```
ref_r <- unlist(mu_df[1, ])
mat <- which(mu_df == 'X', arr.ind = TRUE)
mu_df[mat] <- ref_r[mat[, 2]]

#   c1 c2 c3 c4
#t1  A  I  -  Q
#t2  -  G  K  -
#t3  A  R  -  L
#t4  -  I  -  -
#t5  B  S  B  Q
```

Comment: So, does the small example I've added is clearer? I also corrected the small for loop I provided at the beginning

Comment: Why only the first instance of "X"? will it work if I have more the 1 "X"?

Comment: I was over-complicating it. Check updated answer which will replace all the instances of 'X' in the dataframe.

Comment: Just another small question, do you know how much faster that would be compared to the `for` loop? Sorry for the entire headache, I'm more of a python man, and the transformation to R is not trivial in some cases.

Comment: Depends how big your dataframe is. I would expect this to be significantly faster for large dataframes.